# asp.net: how to use ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, certificate

I created ssl certificate using IIS 5.1 and generated a file certreq.txt. Now what is the next step to use this file. I am a developer and working on a site that is host on my local machine. Is is necessary to get license from any CA?

Please guide me ASAP.

Comment: Please note that you do not get a license from the CA. You get your certificate signed by the CA.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a s[elf-signed cert](http://www.xenocafe.com/tutorials/self_signed_cert_IIS/self_signed_cert_IIS-part1.php), but that will not be very elegant for end users if this is a public website as there is the prompt about cert validity. Otherwise, yes you need to obtain a cert from a CA. I find the best is [Verisign](http://www.verisign.com/), although DEFINITELY not the cheapest. Others are Godaddy, CheapDomain, and pretty much any registrar can help with it.

The link is for 5.1, but you can find [tutorials](http://www.google.com/search?q=iis%20self%20signed%20cert) on all versions. For testing I would go the self signed route.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate generated from IIS, is a self-signed certificate, which can be used to test your website.  However, if you run a public website from a self-signed certificate, every user will get a warning that the site is not safe.  You will eventually need to get a license from a CA when you are ready to publish your site.  Your domain host should provide an SSL certificate service, for something like $50-150/yr.

Comment: Thanks for response. I only want to test my site on my personal pc until i deploy it on the server. I want to open a page with https:// . Now what i have to do? Just create certreq.txt, and give url to that page like https://. But what will be the impact of that certreq.txt file on that perticular webpage?

Comment: I will get license when i will deployee the site, but for testing what is the next step after creating self-signed certificate certreq.txt through iis? Please help me, as my work is stuck bcoz of this...

Answer (score 0):

You can either self sign the certificate or send it to the CA to avoid the do-not-trust this site prompt. [SSLTools Manager](http://www.ssltools.com/manager) is a nifty app that can send your csr to a CA. Not sure about the self-signing feature though.